# Example of VSTO for Excel in C# for setting up and using the Worksheet Change Event?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am attempting to wire-up an event handler for a worksheet Change event in the `private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)` method.

If I accept the entry added by using the tab key,the following line is added to `private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)`:

```
activeWorksheet.Change += ActiveWorksheet_Change;
```

and the following method is added:

```
    private void ActiveWorksheet_Change(Excel.Range Target)
    {

    }
```

This compiles but throws an exception at:

```
activeWorksheet.Change += ActiveWorksheet_Change;
```

Is there a reference with examples on using events with an Excel Add-in using VSTO and C#?

Are there any recent books on using VSTO and C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following code :

```
this.Application.SheetChange += Application_SheetChange; 

private void Application_SheetChange(object Sh, Excel.Range Target)
{
            // your code here
}
```